# CiviHR/hrbank: Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date

Tags: civihr

I'm trying to install the hrbank extension of CiviHR 1.3.0 on a CiviCRM 4.7.13/Ubuntu 16.04/Php7 stack. I get the error "DB Error: unknown error"

The stacktrace in the ConfigAndLog directory shows that a value 0 is used for the date_created field of the civicrm_custom_group, and apparently that is not allowed:

```
Oct 25 08:45:09  [info] Creating canary table

Oct 25 09:10:01  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_display , help_pre , help_post , weight , is_active , table_name , is_multiple , collapse_adv_display , created_date , is_reserved ) VALUES ('Bank_Details' , 'Bank Details' , 'Individual' , 'Tab' ,  0 , '' , '' ,  12 ,  1 , 'civicrm_value_bank_details_9' ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date 'at row 1]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_display , help_pre , help_post , weight , is_active , table_name , is_multiple , collapse_adv_display , created_date , is_reserved ) VALUES ('Bank_Details' , 'Bank Details' , 'Individual' , 'Tab' ,  0 , '' , '' ,  12 ,  1 , 'civicrm_value_bank_details_9' ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date' at row 1]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_display , help_pre , help_post , weight , is_active , table_name , is_multiple , collapse_adv_display , created_date , is_reserved ) VALUES ('Bank_Details' , 'Bank Details' , 'Individual' , 'Tab' ,  0 , '' , '' ,  12 ,  1 , 'civicrm_value_bank_details_9' ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date' at row 1]"]
)


Oct 25 09:10:01  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(229): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...")
#3 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...")
#4 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...", "1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date' at row 1")
#7 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...")
#9 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2438): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...")
#10 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1060): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , style , collapse_d...")
#11 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(482): DB_DataObject->insert()
#12 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(130): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
#13 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(207): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->copyData(Object(CRM_Core_DAO_CustomGroup), Object(SimpleXMLElement), TRUE, "name")
#14 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(78): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->customGroups(Object(SimpleXMLElement), (Array:2))
#15 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(56): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->runXmlElement(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#16 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions/civihr/civihr-1.3.0/hrbank/CRM/HRBank/Upgrader/Base.php(95): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->run("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Pag...")
#17 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions/civihr/civihr-1.3.0/hrbank/CRM/HRBank/Upgrader/Base.php(250): CRM_HRBank_Upgrader_Base::executeCustomDataFileByAbsPath("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Pag...")
#18 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions/civihr/civihr-1.3.0/hrbank/hrbank.civix.php(45): CRM_HRBank_Upgrader_Base->onInstall()
#19 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions/civihr/civihr-1.3.0/hrbank/hrbank.php(50): _hrbank_civix_civicrm_install()
#20 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(76): hrbank_civicrm_install()
#21 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(48): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->callHook(Object(CRM_Extension_Info), "install")
#22 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(229): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->onPreInstall(Object(CRM_Extension_Info))
#23 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(181): CRM_Extension_Manager->install((Array:1))
#24 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(431): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#25 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#26 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")
#27 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#28 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#29 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#30 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(384): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#31 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(168): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)
#32 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(121): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#33 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#34 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#35 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#36 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#37 /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#38 /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#39 {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more of an issue with CiviCRM/HR than MySQL

Passing 000 like dates is deprecated in newer versions of MySQL so approaches that disable `NO_ZERO_DATE` are a little short sighted (though they might get you out of an immediate pickle).

Hence the answer is probably to fix the CiviHR and/or CiviCRM. In most cases, I imagine the fix is no harder than changing the MySQL setting.

e.g. a fix like https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/pull/279/commits/5edb7bf772d5bb89302a8970bd7fae37672b5beb solve the problem for the mailchimp extension.

A fix to somewhere like CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php might be good to solve the problem more globally.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when installing CiviVolunteer recently. I was using a similar setup: Ubuntu 16.04, CiviCRM 4.7.16 and MySQL 5.7.17. This is likely a MySQL issue: recent versions of MySQL have changed the default behavior with respect to the `NO_ZERO_DATE` setting. I just posted an issue with CiviVolunteer here which might be helpful: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-299

Here's my workaround, I'm guessing this will work for you too:

- Login to the CiviCRM database and examine the current sql_mode setting:
  `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`
- Note the current setting parameters, if `NO_ZERO_DATE` is set it should be disabled
- Edit: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and add the settings from the previous step with `NO_ZERO_DATE` omitted. For example, add the following to the end of the config file:    `sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`
  Note: this workaround fix is fairly broad and affects all database instances, this could probably be fine tuned somewhat.
- Restart MySQL and reinstall your CiviCRM extension
- After successful installation, revert the `sql_mode` settings by removing the above line from `mysqld.cnf`.

Related links:

- https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19546
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000